# kendo grid custom filter with local storage

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo UI version: "2015.1.318", which is setup to work with local storage when consumer switch offline.
My problem is, when i use client side custom filter, it always request to server to get data. How can i filter with grid's datasource (now is local storage).

This is my Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<InventoryModel>()
    .Name("InventoryIndexGrid")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "grid", key = "InventoryItemGrid", @style = "height:auto !important" })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.ItemDateStr).Title("Inventory Date").HtmlAttributes(new
        { @style = "text-align: center" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: center" })
    .ClientTemplate("<a onclick=\"onSelectDate('#=ItemDateStr#\','#=UserNameDisp#','#=TenantID#')\" class='' >#=ItemDateStr#</a>");
columns.Bound(p =>p.InventoryType).Title("Type").Sortable(false).Filterable(false).Width("8%").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: center" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new {
@style = "text-align: center" });
    columns.Bound(p => p.UserName).Title("Created By").Sortable(false).Filterable(false).Width("82%").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: left" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align: center"     });
    columns.Bound(p => p.UserNameDisp).Hidden(true);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Custom()
    .Text("")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @Title = "Create new Inventory", id = "btnAddNew", @class = "btn btn-default btn-crm btn-crm-action fa fa-plus-square-o", @style = "padding-top:10px;height:34px; width:40px" }))
    .AutoBind(true)
    .Reorderable(p => p.Columns(true))
    .Resizable(p => p.Columns(true))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable.Refresh(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().PageSize(1000).Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ItemID))
    .Create(update => update.Action("Save", "MealPeriod"))
    .Read(read =>
    {
        read.Action("GetIndex", "Inventory", new { type = "food" });
        read.Data("InventoryIndexGridAdditionalData");
    })).Events(c => c.DataBound("onDataBoundInventoryIndexGrid"))
    )
```

And this is how i use custom filter:

```
var gridInventory = $("#InventoryLocationGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var keyLocalStorage = 'offline_data_inventory_' + $('#TenantID').val() + '_'     + type + '_' + $('#ItemDate').val();
var tempDataInventory = setaJs.getLocalStorage(keyLocalStorage);
if (tempDataInventory) {
    var dataSourceInventory = tempDataInventory;
    gridInventory.dataSource.data(dataSourceInventory);

    var filter = new Array(),
        keyword = $('#Keyword').val(),
        category = $("#ChooseCategory").val();
    if (keyword) {
        filter.push({ field: "ItemName", operator: "contains", value: keyword });
    }

    gridInventory.dataSource.filter(filter);
}
```

Please help!

Comment: You want to have prefiltered grid when user visits page next time? If so, you can use [filter](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#filter) event and as you already used localstorage. However I am not sure if I understand correctly to your question?

Comment: I want to use custom filter to search data in that grid. Data of grid is now loaded from local storage. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

There is not a simple answear. You have your data in local storage but you still keep old dataSource in your grid. Here:

```
.Read(read =>
    {
        read.Action("GetIndex", "Inventory", new { type = "food" });
        read.Data("InventoryIndexGridAdditionalData");
    })
```

you are tring to get data from `Inventory/GetIndex` but you have it already in your js local storage, so I think that it makes two requests for same data on the first place.

I recommend to rewrite your grid in JavaScript and use data from your storage like this:

```
var keyLocalStorage = 'offline_data_inventory_' + $('#TenantID').val() + '_'     + type + '_' + $('#ItemDate').val();
var tempDataInventory = setaJs.getLocalStorage(keyLocalStorage);

$("#InventoryIndexGrid  ").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: tempDataInventory,
        ...
    },
   ...
});
```

Otherwise you will end with a lot of ugly JavaScript code for filtering and other data operations and you will have problems to change/add anything in the future.

Here is example of local data grid in JS: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/local-data-binding